# SQL Server 2008 Permission to stop the services

Tags: sql-server

What's the permission required to stop/start an SQL Server service?
I just created a login (SQL Authentication, public server role, no special permission, no database mapping) and found I can stop/restart the SQL instance through SSMS with this login. This is not what I want.

Comment: Might be better on serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSMS does not restart the service with the login you ue to perform queries with it, it uses the desktop/rdp user.

If you are logged into your desktop as a domain admin or local admin of the server your are connected to, and run SSMS from that desktop, you will be able to restart the SQL service. You can also restart the sql service as that user from the services.msc [MMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console).